# working with lf x0A in bash terminal

Tags: macos, bash

I'm mystified why the variable $lf isn't printing out when using hexdump -C

This is a copy with comments added from a run in macOS 10.10.5 bash terminal.

```
mac $ lf=$(echo -ne  "\x0a")
# What happened to the lf?
mac $ echo -n ${lf} | hexdump -C
# The lf seems to be working or should it be two blank lines? 
mac $ echo $lf

# one lf as expected.
mac $ echo "" | hexdump -C
00000000  0a                                                |.|
00000001
# only one lf as expected.
mac $ echo | hexdump -C
00000000  0a                                                |.|
00000001
# since echo return an lf, why not use this fact to create lf
mac $ lf=$(echo)
# Why no lf?
mac $ echo -n ${lf} | hexdump -C
mac $ echo $lf

# one lf where I'd expect to see two. 
mac $ echo  ${lf} | hexdump -C
00000000  0a                                                |.|
00000001

# cr seems to be working as expected.

mac $ cr=$(echo -ne  "\x0D")
mac $ echo -n $cr | hexdump -C
00000000  0d                                                |.|
00000001
```

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`:

> **Command Substitution**
>
> [...]
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, *with any trailing newlines deleted.*

Comment: So why am I getting only one lf?  echo  ${lf} | hexdump -C

Comment: how do I find out what is in the $lf variable?

Comment: Newlines are handled specially, try all the commands you've run with a printable character like `a` to see how `bash` handles each case.

Comment: And if you just want to assign a newline character you can use `\n` directly, no need to pass it through `echo` first.

Comment: mac $ char="\n";
mac $ echo $char;
which prints out"\n".  How?

Comment: @historystamp `foo=$'\n'; echo "a${foo]b"